# Google apps script: urlfetchapp - service invoked too many times

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which calls in many cells a user specific function. This function fetches 3-4 specific relatively short web pages and parses them. The pages change only once a day, but I can't/dont know how to force my spreadsheet fetch each page only once a day and the use a cache copy. 
I believe during refresh after ~20 fetches an urlfetchapp error occurs. "Service invoked too many times".

I try to find a workaround for this problem. I think this error occurs because of many URL-fetches (even for the same URL, with unchanged content), not because of many parsings.

If this is true, how can reduce the number of fetches? For example can I download the pages somewhere and parse them locally? Can I use some kind of caching for web pages in google spreadsheet? Would it help, if I save a copy of this files an my google drive where the spreadsheet resides?
Can I increase the limits for URLfetchapp?
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into using the [Cache service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_cache), which was created for use cases like this. [This blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/caching-in-cloud-with-google-script.html) introducing the service shows some basic usage.

Comment: Thanks, really useful pattern.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid a similar problems, i've implemented a workaround. It isn't very elegant but it works. It uses *Utilities.sleep()* in a loop:

```
function urlFetchWihtoutError(url) {
  const NB_RETRY = 10;
  var nbSecPause = 1.5;
  var nbErr = 0;
  while (nbErr < NB_RETRY) {
    try {
      if (nbErr > 0) SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Here we go again.");
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      return res;
    }
    catch (error) {
      nbErr++;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Let's pause the system during " + nbSecPause + " seconds. Loop number: " + nbErr);
      Utilities.sleep(nbSecPause * 1000)
      nbSecPause += 0.5;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding cache was exactly what was needed for me. So I implemented a function fetch(url) which uses a cache and that way avoids the replicate calls.

```
function fetch(url) {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var result = cache.get(url);
  if(!result) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    result = response.getContentText();
    cache.put(url, result, 21600);
  }
  return result;
}
```